# Is it possible to specify custom query for list method in Grails?

Tags: hibernate, grails

I'm trying to apply Hibernate java domain classes for our Grails application. The table contains some columns which are actually a set of unrelated fixed length subfields (for example column COL_A CHAR(10) contains subflelds SF_A1 CHAR(2), SF_A2 CHAR(1),  SF_A3 CHAR(3), the rest is unused, these subfields are unknown to the database, the database knows the COL_A only). To make life easier for developers I defined domain class with sfA1, sfA2, sfA3 properties as they have business meaning, leaving the COL_A out of game as it's just an casual space for them.

I defined custom  INSERT and UPDATE queries to make this scheme work with SQLInsert and SQLUpdate annotations and they do work. Also I managed to load record with NamedNativeQuery and Loader annotations. The only thing I can't customize is the query generated by the domainClass.list method called in the index method of the controller. It generates the query like "select ..., SF_A1, SF_A2, SF_A3, ... from ..." and this query fails as SF_An columns are unknown to the database. So the question: Is it possible to override the query generated in domainClass.list method with some custom query using the Hibernate/javax.persistence annotations?

PS: Yes, I have backup plan to define view over this table with all the required subfield declared explicitly, but I'd prefer to use java way only if such exists.

Answer (score 0):

You can override any method in Groovy using metaprogramming if you so choose. In the context of Grails putting this in `BootStrap.groovy` will override the `list` method from GORM:

```
Foo.metaClass.static.list = {->
   // my custom impl here
}
```

Comment: Thank you Graeme, I explored the solution, but it looks a bit difficult for the beginner like me. If I undestood ot correctly, I have to re-implement the whole method' logic which is not an easy walk. But I got another idea: replace the list method call in the controller with the call of Hibernate named query list method.
[code]
[/code]

Comment: Foo.withSession {s-> q = s.getNamedQuery ('Foolst')
    q.setMaxResults (params.max)
    q.setFirstResult (params.offset) /* simplified, check existense before */
    return q.list() }

Answer (score 0):

You should probably be defining these columns / fields in your GORM model as transients

http://grails.org/doc/2.3.4/ref/Domain%20Classes/transients.html

This will tell GORM not to consider them real fields. Then I would have COL_A in your GORM mapping something like this maybe

```
class MyDomain {
  static transients=['sfA1','sfA2','sfA3']
  String sfA1
  String sfA2
  String sfA3
  String colA

  static mapping = {
    //Mappings for colA go here
  }

  public String getSfA1() {
    return colA?.substring(0,2)
  }

  public void setSfA1(String value) {
     //Set colA here with values in the specific position
  }

}
```

Also for changing your query (i.e. to query off these values) I would look into GORM namedQueries. you can call these before calling .list in a chain and use advanced hibernate criteria. (including sqlRestriction)

Comment: Thank you. Though I use Hibernate, not GORM, domain classes, but javax.persistense has the Transient annotation too and it was the first thing I played with (for a long time). Unfortunately I was unable to hide colA property this way, so I falled down to the custom queries